# How to dynamically add any number of images to web form where the source string is in a database?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi I am trying to set up a page for users to view details of specific cars and photos relating to the cars. So far I am using a sql table to hold the path of the images and then assigning each path as a "ImageUrl" attribute to img tags that I have manually created.

My question is: Is there a way to have the img tags dynamically created and assign a "ImageUrl" accordingly depending on how many related entities are in the table because the number of pictures will change? If this is not possible could anyone provide any alternatives?

Types of scripts I am using in other parts of my web form are C#, javacript, sqlcommand. I am fairly new at this and my search only show how to assign the ImageUrl in the code behind and that is what I have done. Thank you ahead of time.

This is what I have for the img tags:

```
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Default.png" />

     <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Default.png" />
```

And this is the code behind:

```
      List<string> folder = new List<string>();

        while (readerPhoto.Read())
        {
            folder.Add(readerPhoto["Folder"].ToString());
        }

        switch (folder.Count)
        { 
            case 1:
                Image1.ImageUrl = folder[0];
                break;
            case 2:
                Image1.ImageUrl = folder[0];
                Image2.ImageUrl = folder[1];
       //and so fourth.......
```

08/07/12. New attempt code (the images are created dynamically but the "src" attribute is not assigned correctly):

```
   .aspx 
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CarsConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT Folder FROM Cars INNER JOIN Photos ON Cars.SN = Photos.Cars_SN WHERE (Cars.SN = @SN)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="SN" Name="SN" QueryStringField="SN" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:ListView ID="lvPhotos" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="imgListImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<% Eval("Folder") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Html output a broken image icon and the script as:

```
   <img id="MainContent_ListView1_imgListImage_0" src="<%%20Eval("Folder")%20%>" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: somehow i missed that you use sql table and not the file.
EDIT 2: fixed binding error

Basically you dont need any code behind at all. You need SqlDataSource and ListView and bind second to first one.

```
.aspx

<asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnString%>"
      SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Table">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:ListView ID="lvImages" runat="server" DataSource="SqlDataSource1">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image ID="imgListImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Folder") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

[ListView on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried your code but there was a little problem with the ".ReadAll()" method. It is not recognized, throwing an error that says I need a using directive or assembly reference. The intelliSense usually help me out with this and I also tried to look it up but had no luck.

Comment: I have the following using statements:     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

Comment: The code is not using the Eval method properly. Html render it as         <img id="MainContent_ListView1_imgListImage_0" src=<%%20Eval("Folder")%20%>;">

Comment: update your question with code you come up with so far, please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the data binding markup syntax (note the `#`):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="imgListImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Folder") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```